# Fix to prevent multiple macros runs to overwrite one another data

Tags: vba, excel

***EDIT**

Alright so, a change of direction. Instead of looping through the files, I have created 10 separate macros for each file and make the run under a single button. Individually, each macro runs prefectly. However, when I put them all to run together using the code below, it each macro runs one after another but everytime a new macro runs, it overwrites the data pasted before. Any recommendation as to how can I keep the changes from the previous macros? I have tried the simpliest that came to mind, that is to save the workbook at each interval but that didn't work. Help?

```
Sub UpdateDate_Click()
    Call Sakinah_Update
    Call Sasita_Update
    Call Mashitah_Update
    Call NoorAzawati_Update
    Call NurHidayah_Update
    Call NurulIzzati_Update
    Call NurulShazwani_Update
    Call Rohaizad_Update
    Call Shahrani_Update
    Call Shahrudin_Update

    MsgBox "Updated Succesully"
End Sub
```

*EDIT EDIT
Might I add this is the code that I have replicated for all of the macros. Changed the worksheet names for all. Is it because of this code that the macros are overwriting one another?

```
Sub Sasita_Update()
    Dim readLastCell As Long
    Dim readLastCellNameSheet As Long
    Dim billNumber
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim billNumberNamesheet As Long

    Dim sasitaWorkBookPath As String
    Dim excelFilePath
    Dim sasitaWorkBook As Workbook

    excelFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    excelFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    strFilename = Dir(excelFilePath & "\*xlsm")
    sasitaWorkBookPath = excelFilePath & "\Sasita.xlsm"

    SheetName = "Sasita"
    readLastCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1000
    readLastCellNameSheet = sasitaWorkBook.Sheets("Sasita").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1000

    For x = 4 To readLastCellNameSheet
        cell = "A" & x
        billNumber = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value

        If Len(billNumber) = 0 Then Exit For

        For N = 4 To readLastCellNameSheet
            cell = "A" & N
            billNumberNamesheet = sasitaWorkBook.Worksheets("Sasita").Range(cell).Value
            If Len(billNumberNamesheet) = 0 Then Exit For

            If billNumberNamesheet = billNumber Then
                cell = "R" & N & ":" & "AV" & N
                copycell = "R" & x & ":" & "AV" & x
                sasitaWorkBook.Worksheets("Sasita").Range(cell).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range(copycell)
            End If
        Next N
    Next x

    ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
    sasitaWorkBook.Close True             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Set sasitaWorkBook = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    'MsgBox "Updated Succesully"
End Sub
```

Comment: please set `workbooks`

Comment: You're using variables such as `sasitaworkbook` and `sakinahworkbook` which haven't been set, these need to be set like this: `Set sasitaworkbook = Workbooks(sasitaworkbookpath)` and `Set sakinahworkbook = Workbooks(sakinahworkbookpath )`

Comment: @Jordan you were on the right path but `Set sasitaworkbook = Workbooks(sasitaworkbookpath)` won't work with a path. `Workbooks()` needs a workbook name only (without path) like `Workbooks("MyWbName.xlsx")` or you need to use the [Workbooks.Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) to open a workbook that isn't open yet (specifying the path) like: `Set sasitaworkbook = Workbooks.Open(sasitaworkbookpath)`.

Comment: @jordan I've tried making changes accordingly but I figured the new solution is a cheat way to achieve what is needed. I have described the new problem. :)

Comment: @Peh Thank you for the feedback. Though even with that, I can't incorporate it and decided with another direction. Any ideas? :)

Comment: @Peh Thank you for the feedback. Though even with that, I can't incorporate it and decided with another direction. Any ideas? :)